# OpenCv in Java: DescriptorExtractor is deprecated. What do I use instead?

Tags: java, opencv, opencv-stitching

I have some sample code which uses OpenCV (Java wrapper) to stitch 2 images together.  It refers to a class "DescriptorExtractor" which is deprecated.  I can't find any information in the official web documentation or the source-code  about what I should use instead.  I always get annoyed when something is deprecated and it doesn't tell you what you should use instead.

Can anyone help me?

I'm using OpenCV 3.4.1 with pre-built Windows libraries.

The official documentation for the class seems to be [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/features2d/DescriptorExtractor.html).

The "FeatureDetector" class is likewise deprecated, likewise without any hint about what to use instead.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that `Deprecated` annotation in Java should have come with a required parameter which would provide information about the successor of the deprecated element, if any.

In OpenCV version 3.4.5 (and maybe earlier) in C++ docs `DescriptorExtractor` is defined as a type alias for `Feature2D` (see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d2/d75/namespacecv.html)):

```
typedef Feature2D DescriptorExtractor
```

so I believe you should switch to [`org.opencv.features2d.Feature2D`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/javadoc/org/opencv/features2d/Feature2D.html) class in your Java code updating its usages as appropriate.

With OpenCV wrappers (including ones for Java and Python) and corresponding auto-generated documentation, it is usually hard to infer any usage information - it is a good idea to consult with C++ sources and documentation, which appears to be hand-written.